# Torque : estimate walltime value before running job

Tags: pbs, torque

Is there anybody who know if there is a way to estimate `walltime` value or "hours of calculation" needed to run a job before running It ?

tank you very much 
best regards

Comment: You are the one who should know how long your application takes for a given setup, no? We surely don't. 
Or are you asking what `walltime` means?

Comment: yes, how long a job takes for a given setup. Some jobs launched by users are not running because walltime value is too small (or I suppose too small). For ex, a job had walltime=40h and didn't run, the user updated walltime to 100h and the job ran

Comment: Well, you can certainly define queues that only run jobs with a certain walltime range. Maybe that's what you're seeing?